# Navigation Drawer not working in actual Android Device

Tags: java, android, xml, navigation-drawer

I know this question has been asked before too but I didn't find the solution through those posts, so I have no other option but to ask the question now. Been trying for hours now can't able to figure out why my navigation drawer is working in the actual emulator but when I try to connect an android phone using the usb cable it just crashes and stops the app and shows me app keeps crashing. I can't figure out the work around for this, so I need help.

Here is my activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:openDrawer="start"
    android:background="#EEE3CB"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            android:background="#F9E0BB"
            app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_baseline_menu_24"
            android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="Discrete Math Topics"
                android:textSize="28dp"
                />

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:stretchColumns="1"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

            <TableRow>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:text="Logic" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn2"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:text="Sets" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn3"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:text="Chapter3" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn4"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:text="Chapter4" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn5"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:text="Chapter5" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn6"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:text="Chapter6" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn7"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:text="Chapter7" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn8"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:text="Chapter8" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn9"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:text="Chapter9" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn10"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:text="Chapter10" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn11"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:text="Chapter11" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn12"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:text="Chapter12" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn13"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:text="Chapter13" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn14"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:text="Chapter14" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn15"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:minHeight="48dp"
                    android:text="Chapter15" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn16"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:minHeight="48dp"
                    android:text="Chapter16" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            app:adSize="BANNER"
            app:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-5886553399470613/3766483794"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/menu_header"
        app:menu="@menu/main_menu"
        android:id="@+id/navigationView"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        />
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

My MainActivity.java file

```
package com.example.mathprojectraoli;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.AdapterStatus;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.InitializationStatus;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.OnInitializationCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

import java.util.Map;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private AdView mAdView;
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    NavigationView navigationView;
    Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigationView);
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

//        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

//        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle= new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.open, R.string.close);
//        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
//        toggle.syncState();
//
//        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


        MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(@NonNull InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
                }
        });
        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);


        String[] activityNames = {
            "com.example.mathprojectraoli.Chapter1",
            "com.example.mathprojectraoli.Chapter2",
            "com.example.mathprojectraoli.Chapter3",
            "com.example.mathprojectraoli.Chapter4",
            "com.example.mathprojectraoli.Chapter5",
            "com.example.mathprojectraoli.Chapter6",
            "com.example.mathprojectraoli.Chapter7",
            "com.example.mathprojectraoli.Chapter8",
            "com.example.mathprojectraoli.Chapter9",
            "com.example.mathprojectraoli.Chapter10",
            "com.example.mathprojectraoli.Chapter11",
            "com.example.mathprojectraoli.Chapter12",
            "com.example.mathprojectraoli.Chapter13",
            "com.example.mathprojectraoli.Chapter14",
            "com.example.mathprojectraoli.Chapter15",
            "com.example.mathprojectraoli.Chapter16"};
        Button buttons[] = {
                findViewById(R.id.btn1),
                findViewById(R.id.btn2),
                findViewById(R.id.btn3),
                findViewById(R.id.btn4),
                findViewById(R.id.btn5),
                findViewById(R.id.btn6),
                findViewById(R.id.btn7),
                findViewById(R.id.btn8),
                findViewById(R.id.btn9),
                findViewById(R.id.btn10),
                findViewById(R.id.btn11),
                findViewById(R.id.btn12),
                findViewById(R.id.btn13),
                findViewById(R.id.btn14),
                findViewById(R.id.btn15),
                findViewById(R.id.btn16)};

        for(int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++)
        {
            final String activityName = activityNames[i];
            buttons[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    try {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Class.forName(activityName));
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my menu_header.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:background="#213555"
    android:gravity="bottom">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/discrete_math_logo"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Discrete Mathematics"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is main_menu.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item android:id="@+id/home"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_home_24"
            android:title="Home"/>

        <item android:id="@+id/AboutUs"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_about_us_24"
            android:title="About Us"/>

        <item android:id="@+id/Contacts"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_contacts_24"
            android:title="Contacts"/>
    </group>
    <item android:title="Communicate">
        <menu>
            <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
                <item android:id="@+id/Share"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_share_24"
                    android:title="Share"/>
                <item android:id="@+id/Rate"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_rate_review_24"
                    android:title="Rate this App"/>
                <item android:id="@+id/Feedback"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_send_24"
                    android:title="Send Feedback"/>
            </group>
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

I commented out those codes because only then the app works in my android device or else it just crashes. I think there is something related to those codes that is causing the problem. It would be a great help if the app started working on the android device.

Just for more reference I'm providing a screenshot of the app running in the emulator.

[Main layout for the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfHQ5.png)

[Navigation Drawer working in the emulator but not in android device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCegT.png)